# Interpretation of branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

In wikipedia, I found that a branch cut can be thought of as a sum of infinitely many poles arranged along a line in the complex plane with infinitesimal residues. And wiki takes $ln(\frac{z+1}{z-1})$ for an example. See [Continuum of poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Continuum_of_poles).

This is quite an interesting interpretation to me. So I am wondering if there is any similiar way to explain the branch cut of $\sqrt{\frac{z+a}{z+b}}$? Like writting it into a integral manner?